# Port redirect 443 to 8443 doesnt work for my tomcat instance

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, tomcat, port-forwarding

im using ubuntu headless server 18.04 on a dedicated host server. 
The hoster has external firewall, where i opened the ports 8443,443 (tcp).
On my ubuntu server im using iptables, where i redirected the port 443 to 8443 with  the table nat.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

also i opened in inbound & outbound the ports 443& 8443.

i can still access the tomcat instance with example.com:8443 and have no problem  but example.com doesnt response.
looking in iptables i dont see any drop packet. On my tomcat istance i doesnt change the server.xml. The Connector listen 8443.
I dont know, where is the issue ?
I hope some experts can help me to fix the problem.

kind regards

blackbeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need here is a reverse proxy (such as Nginx) that can do SSL termination for you on port 443 and then pass the request to Tomcat on port 8443.

SSL/TLS is complex, and in my view, relying on IPTABLES to handle the SSL handshake and get your request to the Tomcat application is not a good idea.

If you really need to use IPTABLES, connect to the service with `openssl` and find out exactly what is happening. Report output here and more help might be available.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443
```

The issue may also be that you're using the `nat` table. My understanding is that rules for this table are only applied if the requests are being routed *through* the server, as opposed to be routed to a different port on the same ip address.

A reverse proxy would remove a lot of this complexity, and give you lots more functionality (eg rate limiting, access control etc etc) to boot.

Comment: An alternative would be to let Tomcat listen on port `443`.

Comment: That would mean running Tomcat as a root privileged user which is a non-standard configuration for Tomcat.

Comment: On Linux it is enough to run Tomcat with the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability, to bind ports under 1024. Debian 10 does it by default using **systemd**, while Debian 9 requires the use of **authbind** (by changing a value in `/etc/default/tomcat`).

Comment: But if i start apache or nginx  as reverse proxy, i will also start this service as root, where is now the security difference between to start tomcat as root or apache ????

Comment: Standard web servers like Nginx or Apache are designed to be publicly exposed (ie use privileged ports). They start up as root (allowing use of privileged ports), but they fork sub-process using jailed (non-shell) users to accept connections. That means that an attacker can never access root privilege. Tomcat doesn't use this mechanism, so if you start it as root, the connection is initiated with root privileges. Tomcat is designed as an application server rather than as a publicly facing web server.

Comment: its a stable (no troubling)  to run in production environment  tomcat, reverse proxy apache/nginx, and mysql  on the same server ? Or recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on which interface your tomcat is bound to. If it's bound to the loopback interface then this isn't going to work at all.

Mostly the REDIRECT target is used with a specified interface like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

(replace eth1 with the actual network interface that tomcat is running on)

REDIRECT is a convenience method for the DNAT target, so if the above doesn't work you might try something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:8443
```

(replace 10.0.0.1 with the ip address of your machine)